# jQuery .click on TD not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm just trying to get a message box to pop up when I click a cell in my table. I have seen many threads about $("td").click(function () {  etc, but these are not working for my table. I  cannot find out why.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="tableArea">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="green" id='a1'>1</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

And the javascript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("td").click(function(e) {
        alert('Anything');
    });
</script>
```

I do not see a difference in this code than in many of the other threads, but this is not working.  Note: I'm using Bootstrap, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Put your code inside of a `$(function(){ });` block (shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ });`).

Comment: try `$(function(){$("td").click(function(e) {
        alert('Anything');
    });});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should capture the click event after $(document).ready().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("td").click(function(e) {
            alert('Anything');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Here you have a jsfiddle to play around with griffla's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cbCTG/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("td").on('click', function(e) {
        alert('Anything');
    });
});
```

just work fine for your markup.

[see it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZSuN/)